# How do you use an inset box-shadow with a background-color with before and after?

Tags: html, css

When assigning a background color of a table cell on hover, the box shadow is covered.

I have found several questions asking something similar, and my understanding is this is correct behavior: background colors do overlay box shadows.

However, I have seen several answers on here using a "mask" (new element) or `:before` and `:after`.  The "mask" solution won't work for me as I cannot edit the HTML.

I first tried using borders instead of box shadows, but that moved the rows up and down due to varying heights.

Is this possible?  Row should highlight on hover, cell should highlight a different color on hover, row should have 4px border on hover but cells should not shift up/down on hover.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px blue;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr td:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

table tr td:hover::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  height: 4px;
}

table tr td:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/guqtj4y0/26/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify how you want to accomplish the borders. In your title you `box-shadow`, but in your description you try to do it with `borders`:

> Row should highlight on hover, cell should highlight a different color on hover, row should have 4px border on hover but cells should not shift up/down on hover.

I didn't do it with an actual border. Instead, I set an [`outline`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) and just set an [`outline-offset`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp). This should be what you're looking for.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr:hover {
  background: yellow;
  outline: 4px solid blue;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}

table tr td:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This solution is very convenient because you can pretty easily style an outline. If you, for example, want to add an outline to the specific table cell that is hovered, just add the outline to the cell with the according pseudo-class and you should be ready to go.

Comment: This seems like the best solution - any alternative that avoids messing with the `display` would involve applying the box shadow to the table cell, which results in breaks between each cell and a lot of redundant CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider multiple background to achieve this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px blue;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr td:hover {
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) top,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom,
   yellow;
  background-size:100% 4px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

table tr td:first-child:hover {
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) top,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) left,
   yellow;
  background-size:100% 4px,100% 4px,4px 100% ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
table tr td:last-child:hover {
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) top,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) right,
   yellow;
  background-size:100% 4px,100% 4px,4px 100% ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can optimize like below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px blue;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;  
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) top,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) left,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) right,
   linear-gradient(yellow,yellow);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
}

table tr td:hover {
  background-size:100% 4px,100% 4px, 0 0,0 0,auto;
}

table tr td:first-child:hover {
  background-size:100% 4px,100% 4px, 4px 100%,0 0,auto;
}
table tr td:last-child:hover {
  background-size:100% 4px,100% 4px,0 0,4px 100%,auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another idea with less gradient:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px blue;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;  
  background-image:linear-gradient(yellow,yellow);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
}

table tr td:hover {
  background-size:100% calc(100% - 8px);  
  background-position:center;
}

table tr td:first-child:hover {
  background-size:calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 8px);
  background-position:right;
}
table tr td:last-child:hover {
  background-size:calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 8px);
  background-position:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also consider inset box-shadow on the td elements:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px blue;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;  
}

table tr td:hover {
  background:yellow;
  box-shadow:
    0 4px 0 blue inset,
    0 -4px 0 blue inset;
}

table tr td:first-child:hover {
  box-shadow:
    4px 0 0 blue inset,
    0 4px 0 blue inset,
    0 -4px 0 blue inset;
}
table tr td:last-child:hover {
  box-shadow:
    -4px 0 0 blue inset,
    0 4px 0 blue inset,
    0 -4px 0 blue inset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Clever stuff!  I would have never gotten this.

Answer (score 0):

So to apply the box shadow in this fashion (inset) to your table row you need to modify the `display` of `<tr>` and then apply a little bit of `::after` CSS (which you already had pretty much done).

It's really just a matter of applying them to the correct HTML elements and adding a bit of extra CSS like `pointer-events: none` to ensure that your other hover events are honored.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr { 
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: box-shadow, background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

tr:hover {
  background: red;
}

tr:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

td:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

One thing I would note; if you wanted the box shadow to appear *around* the table row instead of inset, you could achieve that effect without needing to use pseudo elements at all. Simply applying the box shadow to `tr:hover` (without the `inset` declaration) and you're done!

Comment: pay attention, changing the display will break the table layout .. add more content to one of the cells to see the issue